# git stash pop : discard local changes in a single file

Tags: git, git-stash

On my-branch

```
 git stash
 git checkout master
 git pull --rebase
 git checkout my-branch
 git rebase master
 git stash pop
```

Everything is ok but only 1 file has conflicts and I do not want the changes that I stashed. There are bunch of other files which are not conflicting and those changes are needed.

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
  both modified:   /server/Server.java
```

How do I get rid of these changes and have a clean stash pop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout HEAD -- /server/Server.java
```

to discard local changes and check out the state of the file as recorded in HEAD i.e. the current commit.

Comment: Only this did not work. Few files were already staged for commit. So I had to `git reset` followed by  `git checkout /server/Server.java` and finally `git stash drop`

Comment: @Confused Oops missed a bit, I mentioned HEAD but forgot to include it in the command, I’ve edited my answer.